# Generalized hyperbolic distribution in R

Tags: r

How to use the package "generalized hyperbolic distribution" in order to fit the paramters in the [NIG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal-inverse_Gaussian_distribution) distribution to a data set?

Comment: What is the "NIG" distribution?

Comment: The `ghyp` package has functions  `fit.NIGuv` (for univariate data) and a `fit.NIGmv` (for multivariate) data, and it's all very clearly described in the doc for the package. Did you look at it or try it out?

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer. But when I try to use this function I get the message that it can't find this function. which packages do I have to download to be able to use this function? And is there something special I should do when I have downloaded a package in order to make it work?

Comment: @Aniko: NIG is [Normal Inverse Gaussian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal-inverse_Gaussian_distribution)

Answer (score 2):

Developing @Prasad Chalasani's comment, you need to install the `ghyp` package.  When I did, the packages `gtools`, `gdata`, `numDeriv` and `gplots` were also installed automatically.  However, I then got the same error as you `Error: could not find function "fit.NIGuv"`, which I resolved by installing the `bitops` package manually.

The [documentation](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ghyp/ghyp.pdf) gives an example of the following code using `fit.NIGuv()`

```
library(ghyp)
data(smi.stocks)
nig.fit <- fit.NIGuv(smi.stocks[,"SMI"], opt.pars = c(alpha.bar = FALSE),
                     alpha.bar = 1, control = list(abs.tol = 1e-8))
nig.fit
summary(nig.fit)
hist(nig.fit)
```

where the output includes

```
Asymmetric Normal Inverse Gaussian Distribution:

Parameters:
    alpha.bar            mu         sigma         gamma 
 1.0000000000  0.0008370731  0.0112098776 -0.0007205143 

log-likelihood:
5495.705
```

and I think this is the kind of thing you are looking for.